# How can I delete the rest of the line after the second pipe character "|" for every line with python?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I am using notepad++ and I want to get rid of everything after one second (including the second pipe character) for every line in my txt file.

Basically, the txt file has the following format:

```
3.1_1.wav|I like apples.|I like apples|I like bananas    
3.1_2.wav|Isn't today a lovely day?|Right now it is 1 in the afternoon.|....
```

The result should be:

```
3.1_1.wav|I like apples.    
3.1_2.wav|Isn't today a lovely day?
```

I have tried using `\|.*` but then everything after the first pipe character is matched.

Comment: Use `^([^|]*\|[^|]*)\|.*` and replace that with `$1`

Comment: If you only want to match `.wav` files right before the first pipe `^[^|]*\.wav\|[^|]*\K.*` and replace with an empty string. See https://regex101.com/r/yv4QPI/1

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ do this:

- Find what: `^([^\|]*\|[^\|]*).*`
- Replace with: `$1`
- check "Regular expression", and "Replace All"

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start of line
- `(` - start group, can be referenced as `$1`
- `[^\|]*` - scan over any character other than `|`
- `\|` - scan over `|`
- `[^\|]*` - scan over any character other than `|`
- `)` - end group
- `.*` - scan over everything until end of line
- in replace reference the captured group with `$1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but try this:

```
[^wav]\|.*
```

[image: Result from RegExr]

Comment: This works for the example data because before the first occurrence of the pipe there is a `v`, which is excluded by the negated character class `[^wav]` which matches any character except one of `w` `a` or `v`. It does not take into account if it is the second occurrence of the pipe unfortunately.

Comment: I'm guessing that the whole text follow the same pattern, wav files names followed by pipe, so I thought that this would be s simple answer that applies to this question specifically.

Comment: Have a try with `123.wav|I like banana|Yes Bananas|Blah Blah`